# how to pass PHP echo DIV values to dialog box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Each articles are located in DIV tag. Want to make each DIV clickable and once i click DIV, dialog box should display with  appropriate `DVI` values
`$add->tbl_article_content`, `$add->tbl_article_image` my JS dialog box appear for only 1st DIV. how should i do it for all DIV and pass relevant data.

PHP

```
<div class="row">
<?php
    foreach ($data as $value) {
       echo "<div class='col-lg-3'>";
       echo "<p id='target'>" . $value->tbl_article_header . "</p>";
       echo "</div>";       
}
?>
```

Jquery

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
        alert( "relevant DIV database values ??? " );
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `target` as an id you should make it as `class`

```
<div class="row">
<?php
    foreach ($data as $value) {
       echo "<div class='col-lg-3'>";
       echo "<p class='target'>" . $value->tbl_article_header . "</p>";
       echo "</div>";       
   }
?>
```

```js
$( ".target" ).click(function() {
     alert( $(this).html() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='col-lg-3'>
<p class='target'>Value 1</p>
</div>

<div class='col-lg-3'>
<p class='target'>Value 2</p>
</div>

<div class='col-lg-3'>
<p class='target'>Value 3</p>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<div class="row">
<?php
    foreach ($data as $value) {
       echo "<div class='col-lg-3'>";
       echo "<p class='target' data-article=".$add->tbl_article_content.">" . $value->tbl_article_header . "</p>";
       echo "</div>";       
   }
?>
```

```js
$( ".target" ).click(function() {
     alert( $(this).attr('data-article') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='col-lg-3'>
<p class='target' data-article="Articel 1">Head 1</p>
</div>

<div class='col-lg-3'>
<p class='target' data-article="Articel 2">Head 2</p>
</div>

<div class='col-lg-3'>
<p class='target' data-article="Articel 3">Head 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: its work perfectly..but dialog contents same values in div. the question need to show headline on `div` and details on dialog box.

Comment: where are the details located?

Comment: database table  `$value->tbl_article_header` (on DIV), `$add->tbl_article_content`(on Dialog)

Answer (score 0):

the id is unique inside a page  ...  use a class for a group of related div

```
<?php
foreach ($data as $value) {
   echo "<div class='col-lg-3'>";
   echo "<p class='target'>" . $value->tbl_article_header . "</p>";
   echo "</div>";       
}
?>
```

and for js

```
 $( ".target" ).click(function() {
    alert( "relevant DIV database values ??? " );
  });
```